# How to avoid subdomains as self referrals in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, referrals

- I am having a domain site.com, i want to avoid referrals from the subdomains like new.site.com, used.site.com etc.

  - I used the _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'site.com']); but it doesn't worked.
  - can any one help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions here:

1) Use the _addIgnoredRef() method:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiSearchEngines#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addIgnoredRef

2) Put the same GA code on your other subdomains as well.